# How to convert a single array containing strings of objects in Angular4?

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
productData(id){
    this.id=id;
    console.log("id"+this.id);
      let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
return this.http.get(SharedServiceService.productDetails+this.id,{
        headers:headers
        })
      .subscribe(data => { 
          const products = data.json();
          this.productInfo=products;
          this.cart = this.storage.retrieve('cartList');
for(var i=0;i<this.cart.length;i++){
if(this.id==this.cart[i].id){
         this.addedOne=false;
        this.hideCart=true;
        this.continueShopping=false;   
}
}
          
var attr=[];
var storeLoc=[];
          attr.push(this.productInfo);
    console.log("attr",attr);
for(var i=0;i<attr[0].attributes.length;i++){
if((attr[0].attributes[i].name=='Next day store pickup') || (attr[0].attributes[i].name=='Store pickup')|| (attr[0].attributes[i].name=='Delivery price')|| (attr[0].attributes[i].name=='Shipping price')){
    this.prices.push(attr[0].attributes[i]);
        }
    console.log(this.prices);
}

for(var i=0;i<attr[0].attributes.length;i++){
if(attr[0].attributes[i].name=='Stores'){
for(var j=0;j<attr[0].attributes[i].options.length;j++){
    storeLoc.push(JSON.stringify(attr[0].attributes[i].options[j]));
}
}
}
           storeLoc.map((obj) => {
   let data = obj.replace(/”/g, '"');
   data = data.replace(/“/g, '"');
   this.stores.push(JSON.parse(data));
  })
              
          console.log("stores",(this.stores));
          console.log("id info"+JSON.stringify(this.productInfo));
        },
err => {
    console.log("Error!: ",err);
}
        );                              
}
storeLoc= [
                    "{“street”:”3104 Doctors Drive”,”city”:”Los Angeles”,”state code”:”CA”,”state”:”California”,”zip code”:”90017”}",
                    "{“street”:”3358 Cinnamon Lane”,”city”:”San Antonio”,”state code”:”TX”,”state”:”Texas”,”zip code”:”78212”}",
                    "{“street”:”573 May Street”,”city”:”Harold”,”state code”:”KY”,”state”:”Kentucky”,”zip code”:”41635”}",
                    "{“street”:”2836 Cantebury Drive”,”city”:”New York”,”state code”:”NY”,”state”:”New York”,”zip code”:”10013”}",
                    "{“street”:”2935 Kidd Avenue”,”city”:”St George”,”state code”:”AK”,”state”:”Alaska”,”zip code”:”99591”}",
                    "{“street”:”3676 Spirit Drive”,”city”:”Jacksonville”,”state code”:”FL”,”state”:”Florida”,”zip code”:”32220”}",
                    "{“street”:”2134 Shobe Lane”,”city”:”Moody”,”state code”:”AL”,”state”:”Alabama”,”zip code”:”35004”}",
                    "{“street”:”3614 Rhapsody Street”,”city”:”Aiea”,”state code”:”HI”,”state”:”Hawaii”,”zip code”:”96701”}",
                    "{“street”:”1756 Forest Drive”,”city”:”Ashburn”,”state code”:”VA”,”state”:”Virginia”,”zip code”:”22011”}",
                    "{“street”:”686 Upland Avenue”,”city”:”Toledo”,”state code”:”OH”,”state”:”Ohio”,”zip code”:”43609”}",
                    "{“street”:”574 Copperhead Road”,”city”:”Abercrombie”,”state code”:”ND”,”state”:”North Dakota”,”zip code”:”58001”}",
                    "{“street”:”3106 Tecumsah Lane”,”city”:”Van Horne”,”state code”:”IA”,”state”:”Iowa”,”zip code”:”52346”}"
                ]
```

I am working in Angular4 application.I am getting response in the format of an array consisting of strings of objects. Here I need to display each object separately using ngFor.But I am unable to display the data since object data is in string format to display the object properties. Hers is my code:

```js
"options": [
                    "{“street”:”3104 Doctors Drive”,”city”:”Los Angeles”,”state code”:”CA”,”state”:”California”,”zip code”:”90017”}",
                    "{“street”:”3358 Cinnamon Lane”,”city”:”San Antonio”,”state code”:”TX”,”state”:”Texas”,”zip code”:”78212”}",
                    "{“street”:”573 May Street”,”city”:”Harold”,”state code”:”KY”,”state”:”Kentucky”,”zip code”:”41635”}",
                    "{“street”:”2836 Cantebury Drive”,”city”:”New York”,”state code”:”NY”,”state”:”New York”,”zip code”:”10013”}",
                    "{“street”:”2935 Kidd Avenue”,”city”:”St George”,”state code”:”AK”,”state”:”Alaska”,”zip code”:”99591”}",
                    "{“street”:”3676 Spirit Drive”,”city”:”Jacksonville”,”state code”:”FL”,”state”:”Florida”,”zip code”:”32220”}",
                    "{“street”:”2134 Shobe Lane”,”city”:”Moody”,”state code”:”AL”,”state”:”Alabama”,”zip code”:”35004”}",
                    "{“street”:”3614 Rhapsody Street”,”city”:”Aiea”,”state code”:”HI”,”state”:”Hawaii”,”zip code”:”96701”}",
                    "{“street”:”1756 Forest Drive”,”city”:”Ashburn”,”state code”:”VA”,”state”:”Virginia”,”zip code”:”22011”}",
                    "{“street”:”686 Upland Avenue”,”city”:”Toledo”,”state code”:”OH”,”state”:”Ohio”,”zip code”:”43609”}",
                    "{“street”:”574 Copperhead Road”,”city”:”Abercrombie”,”state code”:”ND”,”state”:”North Dakota”,”zip code”:”58001”}",
                    "{“street”:”3106 Tecumsah Lane”,”city”:”Van Horne”,”state code”:”IA”,”state”:”Iowa”,”zip code”:”52346”}"
                ]
```

This is the array I need to display.How can implement the code for this array in Angular4?

Comment: did u tried something ?

Comment: yeah.I tried JSON.parse(options),but it doesnot works

Comment: what does "does not works" mean?  did JSON.parse give you an error? or some unexpected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var options = [
  "{“street”:”3104 Doctors Drive”,”city”:”Los Angeles”,”state code”:”CA”,”state”:”California”,”zip code”:”90017”}",
  "{“street”:”3358 Cinnamon Lane”,”city”:”San Antonio”,”state code”:”TX”,”state”:”Texas”,”zip code”:”78212”}",
  "{“street”:”573 May Street”,”city”:”Harold”,”state code”:”KY”,”state”:”Kentucky”,”zip code”:”41635”}",
  "{“street”:”2836 Cantebury Drive”,”city”:”New York”,”state code”:”NY”,”state”:”New York”,”zip code”:”10013”}",
  "{“street”:”2935 Kidd Avenue”,”city”:”St George”,”state code”:”AK”,”state”:”Alaska”,”zip code”:”99591”}",
  "{“street”:”3676 Spirit Drive”,”city”:”Jacksonville”,”state code”:”FL”,”state”:”Florida”,”zip code”:”32220”}",
  "{“street”:”2134 Shobe Lane”,”city”:”Moody”,”state code”:”AL”,”state”:”Alabama”,”zip code”:”35004”}",
  "{“street”:”3614 Rhapsody Street”,”city”:”Aiea”,”state code”:”HI”,”state”:”Hawaii”,”zip code”:”96701”}",
  "{“street”:”1756 Forest Drive”,”city”:”Ashburn”,”state code”:”VA”,”state”:”Virginia”,”zip code”:”22011”}",
  "{“street”:”686 Upland Avenue”,”city”:”Toledo”,”state code”:”OH”,”state”:”Ohio”,”zip code”:”43609”}",
  "{“street”:”574 Copperhead Road”,”city”:”Abercrombie”,”state code”:”ND”,”state”:”North Dakota”,”zip code”:”58001”}",
  "{“street”:”3106 Tecumsah Lane”,”city”:”Van Horne”,”state code”:”IA”,”state”:”Iowa”,”zip code”:”52346”}"
 ];
  
  var newArray = [];
  
  options.map((obj) => {
   let data = obj.replace(/”/g, '"');
   data = data.replace(/“/g, '"');
   newArray.push(JSON.parse(data));
  })
    
   console.log('newArray', newArray);
```

Comment: @srujana check your double quotes is invalid to json parse so that I will do replace that double quotes standard inside map and push into new array

Comment: Iam getting unexpected token s in JSON at position 3
    at Object.parse error.

Comment: It's working.Thanks.I have done small mistake of stringifying the data.I removed it and it works

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to parse (JSON.parse) your data so it's in a format that *ngFor can work with. If you're running into issues it's likely a syntax issue with your parsing, so that's where you should give your attention. Once you have that parsing solved it will work, as this is exactly the kind of iteration *ngFor was created to handle.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the string that you are trying to parse. Paste your JSON object at the website(json parser and formatter) below.

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You can debug and find the issue with your data.

OR

**Not an ideal solution**: Use string manipulation to construct your object. Using string.split on **"** you will get array of strings, using that array you can convert it to a **key-value pair** object.